# Complex Irreducible Variety has Rank Equal to Codimension

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $V\subseteq \mathbf C^n$ be an irreducible algebraic variety.

> **Definition.** We define the ***dimension*** of $V$ as the transcendence degree of the fraction field of $\mathbf C[x_1, \ldots, x_n]/I(V)$ over $\mathbf C$.

Note that this makes sense since the irreducibility of $V$ implies that $I(V)$ is prime.

> **Definition.** Let $p\in V$. Define the ***rank*** of $V$ at $p$ as
>   $$\text{rank}_p(V)=\text{dim}\{Df_p:\ f\in I(V)\}\subseteq (\mathbf C^n)^*$$
>   Define the ***rank*** of $V$ as
>   $$\text{rank}(V)= \max_{p\in V}\text{rank}_p(V)$$

In the above definition, $Df_p$ is the covector in $(\mathbf C^n)^*$ which takes $v=(v_1, \ldots, v_n)\in \mathbf C^n$ to $\sum_{i=1}^n \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_i}\right|_pv_i$.

In Whitney's paper *Elementary Structure of Real Algebraic Varieties* (Annals of Math. Vol. 66, No. 3, Nov. 1957) Lemma 2 of Section 8 states

> **Lemma.** A complex irreducible variety $V$ of dimension $r$ has rank $n-r$. Any proper subvariety of $V$ is of dimension $< r$.

For a proof the author refers to Sections 5 and 14 of Chapter X of the book *Methods of Algebraic Geometry, Vol. 2*. This is a very old book.
**I am looking for a more recent text in which this proof can be found.** If someone can see a simple argument for the above Lemma, then please post it here. Thanks.

Comment: I think this may be elementary. A point $p$ is smooth if $\mathrm{rank}_p(V)=n-r$. Then the lemma simply says that any variety has smooth points (which can be found in the first chapter of Hartshorne).

Comment: @FredrikMeyer Thank you. I found the Lemma I need in Hartshorne. Though I have to read from the beginning of the book since I am not familiar with the concepts used in the proof. :P